# How are applications notified when the user changes international settings

Tags: windows, winapi

Whenever the user changes the number format in the control panel (see picture below), Excel gets notified and then displays the numbers according to the changements the user has made.

Does anybody know how exactly the notifications work? Is there some `WM_`message sent? Do you need to subscribe to something in order to get notified?

[image]

Comment: I opened notepad, spy++'d its main window, changed something in the regional dialog & it received a WM_SETTINGCHANGE.

Comment: @AlexK. good point! Good old spy++, I completely forgot about the existence of this program. If you put this as an answer I'll accept and upvote it.